# how to create custom options file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

In my custom module , I just created a custom form using ui- component and added select formelement but don't know how to add custom options?

```
<formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="module\module_name\Model\Config\Source\options"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in your ui form xml file:

```
<formElements>
<select>
<settings>
    <options class="Webkul\Test\Ui\Component\Create\Form\Customer\Options"/>
</settings>
</select>
</formElements>
```

And in `Webkul\Test\Ui\Component\Create\Form\Customer\Options.php:`

```
<?php
 namespace Webkul\Test\Ui\Component\Create\Form\Customer;

     use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
 use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory as 
CustomerCollectionFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
             

class Options implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function __construct(
  CustomerCollectionFactory $customerCollectionFactory, $request ) { 
 $this->customerCollectionFactory = $customerCollectionFactory; $this->request = $request;}
 public function toOptionArray()
             {
                    $arry= array(("label"=>"Test","value"=>"Test");
               return $arry;
                 }
   

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your form element in  UI Component xml file ::

```
<field name="field1">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Cwiser\Faq\Model\Config\Source\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Parent Option</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">item</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">field1</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">210</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Please also create below file in \Model\Config\Source

```
<?php

namespace Cwiser\Faq\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Options implements ArrayInterface
{

/**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [
            0 => [
                'label' => 'Please select',
                'value' => 0
            ],
            1 => [
                'label' => 'Option 1',
                'value' => 1
            ],
            2  => [
                'label' => 'Option 2',
                'value' => 2
            ],
            3 => [
                'label' => 'Option 3',
                'value' => 3
            ],
        ];

        return $options;
    }

}
```